# gstreamer: Switch recording from one file to another

Tags: gstreamer

I am writing an application that records incoming video into a file, and every 't' seconds, saves that file and records into a new file. splitmuxsink seems to do achieve this but doesn't serve my purpose because -

- It does not allow overlap between consecutive files. I want the last few seconds of one file to also be present in the next.
- splitmuxsink also has other weird issues (huge latency compared to normal filesink, doesn't record audio as well as filesink, incorrect timestamping of files, etc.)

So, I would like to have the application trigger a time-based callback every 't' seconds. In my pipeline I have a mux through which I write to two files at the same time for a little while (depending on the overlap) and then based on another timer callback, disconnect the older filesink.

I have the following questions -

1. Is the above scheme a good idea? Any better ideas?
2. How do I register a timer callback? Just OS syscalls or does gstreamer provide any API?
3. What's a safe way to disconnect the older filesink? Should it first be disconnected and then sent an EOS signal? I'm a little confused here.
4. Change the time in the pipeline for the new file. A problem in splitmuxsink is that the file is timestamped with the pipeline's running time but this should actually reset each time a new file gets created. (I don't mind not getting an answer for this just yet; it should probably be a separate question altogether.)

To give an idea of the times involved, each file duration may be 5 min and the overlap may be 1%, 3 sec.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would implement the following solution

1. Use [`tee`](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer-plugins/html/gstreamer-plugins-tee.html) element to split a video into 2 dynamically (in runtime) created sources (src pads) with `mux` and `filesink` as downstream elements of each `src`

[image]

2. Dynamically add/remove `tee` src pads 1 and 2 (and attached elements src->mux->filesink) based on your logic. In your case, you would need 2 timers implemented in a standard way for your environment.
3. There is a safe way to disconnect, as you said, "older filesink". In the proposed solution you would need to disconnect/remove "old" src->mux->filesink part of the pipeline by registering blocking [`probe`](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/additional/design/probes.html?gi-language=python) on `tee` src pad you want to remove. For example, safe removal of src1 and it's downstream elements can be implemented like this

   ```
   GstElement* videoTee = gst_bin_get_by_name(GST_BIN(pipeline), "tee");
   GstPad* srcPad = gst_element_get_static_pad(videoTee, "src_1");
   gst_pad_add_probe(srcPad, GST_PAD_PROBE_TYPE_BLOCK_DOWNSTREAM, remove_video_tee_block_probe_cb, &user_data, NULL);
   gst_object_unref(srcPad);
   gst_object_unref(videoTee);
   ```

   and then, in `remove_video_tee_block_probe_cb` callback, src pad and connected mux and filesink can be removed

   ```
   GstPadProbeReturn remove_video_tee_block_probe_cb(GstPad* pad, GstPadProbeInfo* info, gpointer user_data) {
       /*user_data should contain reference to pipeline*/
       StreamData* streamData = (StreamData*)user_data;

       GstElement* videoTee = gst_bin_get_by_name(GST_BIN(streamData->pipeline), "videoTee");
       /*video tee src pad is blocked now and it can be safely removed*/
       gst_element_release_request_pad(videoTee, pad);

       GstElement* mux = gst_bin_get_by_name(GST_BIN(streamData->pipeline),  "mux1");
       GstElement* fileSink =gst_bin_get_by_name(GST_BIN(streamData->pipeline), "sink1");
       /* set state of element from PLAYING to NULL */
       gst_element_set_state(mux, GST_STATE_NULL);
       gst_element_set_state(fileSink, GST_STATE_NULL);
       /* remove elements from pipeline */
       gst_bin_remove(GST_BIN(streamData->pipeline), mux);
       gst_bin_remove(GST_BIN(streamData->pipeline), fileSink);

       gst_object_unref(videoTee);

      /* remove the probe*/
      gst_pad_remove_probe(pad, GST_PAD_PROBE_INFO_ID(info));

      return GST_PAD_PROBE_OK;
   }
   ```

This solution will allow you to control the presence of filesinks in runtime by adding/removing src->mux->filesink parts of pipeline inside timer callbacks based on your logic.

Comment: Thanks. I have a couple of follow-up questions -
1. Looks like I missed mentioning that I have audio as well and video+audio should be recorded in sync. Simplest way to enforce this would be to add the tee after mux element. Eg - video+audio encoded -> matroskamux -> tee -> two filesinks. Problem with this is that the blocking should happen when a key frame is received. Any suggestions how this can be done?
2. When one pad of tee is blocked, does it not affect the other pad in any way?

Comment: @RajatRao, 1. If audio is present you would need to add an "audio" tee after input file is demultiplexed (into video and audio). The solution would look slightly more complicated with an audio present but the idea will remain the same. 2. If there 2 src pads on tee and if you block one, other will continue working without any interruption.

Comment: You also want to send an EOS through the recording queue to finalize the filesink.